# Laravel "Type error: While Updating Records with PUT/PATCH Methods

Tags: php, laravel

When i run the update controller it gives me this error, i tried different solution from this same platform with this error but their fix was to update with separated syntax of save($product) like that. I am using Model Store for authentication and saving the data or editing deleting.

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php on
>   line 138 ◀"

Update Method

```
 public function update(Request $request, Product $Product){
      $store = Store::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
      $updateProduct = $store->product()->save([
         'name'=> $request->input('name'),
         'description' => $request->input('description'),
         'normal_price' => $request->input('normal_price'),
         'sale_price' => $request->input('sale_price'),
         'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
     ]);
         return redirect('product')->with('status', 'Product Updated');
 }
```

View Edit Form

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('product.update', $product->id)}}">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Comment: Use `create()` instead of `save()`

Comment: Create is creating new product not updating the existing one. Save as Product also

Comment: Yes, `create()` is for creating a new product! If you want to update a product, then use `update()`!

Comment: Try like: `Product::where('id', $id)->update([
         'name'=> $request->input('name'),
         'description' => $request->input('description'),
         'normal_price' => $request->input('normal_price'),
         'sale_price' => $request->input('sale_price'),
         'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
     ]);`

Answer (score 5):

When you're using `save()` [Laravel expects model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

Use `create()` method. Change this:

```
$updateProduct = $store->product()->save([
```

To:

```
$updateProduct = $store->product()->create([
```

Or do this:

```
$updateProduct = $store->product()->save(new Product([
    'name'=> $request->input('name'),
    'description' => $request->input('description'),
    'normal_price' => $request->input('normal_price'),
    'sale_price' => $request->input('sale_price'),
    'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
]));
```

Comment: I am using the existing product to update. Why we have to use Save new or create ?

Comment: Create and save New Product is creating new product not updating the existing one.

Comment: @HassamAli if you need to update an existing product, just use `update()`. For example `Product::where('id', $id)->update($arrayWithNewData)`

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned 1st my form Type PUT and UPDATE method in controller, 
Create or Save as is not the solution.

Right Answer and solution is to replace save with UPDATE

```
$updateProduct = $store->product()->where('id', $Product->id)->update([
        'name'=> $request->input('name'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'normal_price' => $request->input('normal_price'),
        'sale_price' => $request->input('sale_price'),
        'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),

    ]);
```

Reminder : For Update method and PUT/PATCH or EDIT use

```
     DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

REF : [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates/%22Laravel%20Docs%22)

Answer (score 0):

Use Update method like this

```
$updateProduct = $store->product()->update([
        'name'=> $request->input('name'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'normal_price' => $request->input('normal_price'),
        'sale_price' => $request->input('sale_price'),
        'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
    ]);
```

Comment: This is creating new product. not updating existing one